# jQuery, check radio button and mark others disabled

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I am working on a custom form. There are 4 radio buttons at the top, one is marked `checked` by default. Based on those radio button values, other radio buttons will be available or not available in another part of the form.  I am having one final issue: 
if someone checked a method field other than "default" and then checked a interval field other than "once" I want the method field to revert back to "default".

I know that `.attr('checked', 'checked');` is the way to check a field but not sure how to best implement it with my code.

Here is an example:

```
<form>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="interval" value="once" checked> Once
    <input type="radio" name="interval" value="weekly"> Weekly
    <input type="radio" name="interval" value="bi-weekly"> Bi-Weekly
    <input type="radio" name="interval" value="monthly"> Monthly
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="method" value="default" checked> Default
    <input type="radio" class="extra" name="method" value="second"> Second
    <input type="radio" class="extra" name="method" value="third"> Third
  </p>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:radio[name=interval]").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") && $(this).val() == 'once') $('.extra').prop('disabled', false).show();
    else $(".extra").prop('disabled', true).hide();
  });
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8cbrp9u/12/)

Comment: So you only want the extra radio to be enabled if the 'once' is checked?

Comment: I'd like to know the business options better. Can't quite work out what the result should be

Comment: @Taplar yes. But I want to ensure that if anything other than once is checked, that "method" is set to value of "default"

Comment: @Pete I have updated to .prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added common classes to the methods and intervals.  If the interval is changed from 'once' it will set the method back to default and enable the extras.  If it is changed back to once, it will enable the methods.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $intervals = $('.interval');
  var $methods = $('.method');

  $intervals.on('change', function() {
    if (this.value !== 'once') {
      $methods.not('.extra').prop('checked', true);
    }

    $methods.filter('.extra').prop('disabled', this.value !== 'once');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="interval" class="interval" value="once" checked> Once
    <input type="radio" name="interval" class="interval" value="weekly"> Weekly
    <input type="radio" name="interval" class="interval" value="bi-weekly"> Bi-Weekly
    <input type="radio" name="interval" class="interval" value="monthly"> Monthly
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="radio" class="method" name="method" value="default" checked> Default
    <input type="radio" class="method extra" name="method" value="second"> Second
    <input type="radio" class="method extra" name="method" value="third"> Third
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input:radio[name=interval]").on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).prop("checked") && $(this).val() != 'once') 
        {
           $('.extra').attr('disabled', false).show();
           $('input[value="default"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
        else $(".extra").attr('disabled', true).hide();
     });
  });
```

Comment: this is close. But it doesn't set the method back to default if other options are checked

Comment: i missed other than "once" statement, i have updated the code,